# Get link to original image with Picasa API

Tags: c#, .net, api, picasa

Hi i need to get link to original image which i uploaded. I'm using this code but link whick i have is on resized image, how can i get link to original once using API (i don't want to manipulate with url bcz its wrong). Thx in advance. Here the code

```
        public void UploadImages(string[] filenames)
    {
        foreach (string file in filenames)
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
            System.IO.FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();
            PicasaEntry entry = (PicasaEntry)service.Insert(
new Uri("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/default"), fileStream, "image/jpeg", file);                
            fileStream.Close();
            urls.Add(entry.Media.Content.Url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a small note: while I understand the purpose of using only provided methods, and am not familiar with the current library, URL manipulation is exactly what it does. It knows 'd' is the size you pass asking for the original. You can do the same.